# Como hacer que la alerta solo se muestre al hacer click en boton y no al recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, php

Hola tengo un formulario dentro de un modal para actualizar contraseña, solo 2 campos, contraseña actual y nueva contraseña. los campos se actualizan bien y me sale la alerta de success, pero al recargar la pagina,me sigue saliendo la alerta pero en este caso la de warning,es como si enviara nuevamente el formulario,(con los mismo datos, y tira la alerta ya que ahora no coinciden los campos de contraseña actual) como evitar esto?

estoy usando PHP para manejar los datos

aqui al actualizar contraseña
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui al recargar la pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <!-- Perfil Modal-->
<div class="modopen fade" id="editpass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Actualizar contraseña</h6><br>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <div class="container-uppass">
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                        <?php require('./partials/usserpass.php') ?>
                        <input type="text" id="IDPerfil" name="idusuario" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_user'] ?>">                      
                        <label>contraseña actual</label>
                        <input type="password" class=" form-control"id="current_password" name="current_password" required>
                        <button id="show-password1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>   
                        <label>Nueva contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" class=" form-control"id="newpassword" name="newpassword" required>                                
                        <button id="show-password2" type="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button> 
                        <div>
                            <input id="updatepass" class="btn-registrar d-inline-block " type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="updatepass">
                        </div>  
                    </form>
                </div>                                   
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#perfilModal" onclick="$('#editpass').modal('hide'); $('#perfilModal').modal('show');">Cancelar</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

aqui el archivo php para los datos y alertas:

```
<?php 
    include("./config/conexion.php");
    require("./config/session.php");

    if (!$conexion) {
        die("Error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }  
    if(!empty($_POST["updatepass"])){              
        $showid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, trim($_POST['idusuario']));
        $current_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, trim($_POST['current_password']));
        $new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, trim($_POST['newpassword']));
        
        $queryCom = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE id_user = ?";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($queryCom);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $showid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if (!password_verify($current_password, $user['password'])) {                
                echo "<script>
                            swal({
                            title: 'Actualizar contraseña',
                            text: 'La contraseña actual no coincide, intenta nuevamente.',
                            icon: 'warning',
                            button: 'Aceptar'
                            });
                            </script>";                                                               
        }else{
            $new_password = password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $queryUp = "UPDATE user SET password ='$new_password' WHERE id_user=$showid";
            if (mysqli_query($conexion, $queryUp)) {               
                    echo "<script>
                            swal({
                            title: 'Actualizar contraseña',
                            text: 'Contraseña cambiada correctamente.',
                            icon: 'success',
                            button: 'Aceptar'
                            });
                            </script>";                                  
            } else {               
                    echo "<script>
                            swal({
                            title: 'Actualizar contraseña',
                            text: 'Error al cambiar contraseña.',
                            icon: 'danger',
                            button: 'Aceptar'
                            });
                            </script>";                                                                
            }           
        }    
    }
?>
```

Comment: Puedes evitar el comportamiento por defecto de un formulario si envías los datos de manera asíncrona con `ajax` o `fetch` y con el método `preventDefault()`. Aquí en la comunidad encuentras muchos ejemplos de como usarlo.

Comment: tu codigo html no concuerda ... hay un boton aceptar que no esta en tu html ...